# iPhone: convert string using HMAC-SHA1

Tags: iphone, hmacsha1

i want to generate HMAC-SHA1 of NSString type variable. I see the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756492/objective-c-sample-code-for-hmac-sha1) but this method give me error in `CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);`

and

`NSString *hash = [HMAC base64Encoding];` 
line.

Please suggest how can I generate the HMAC-SHA1 of any string.

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CCHmac'

error: 'kCCHmacAlgSHA256' undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you got this at the top of your source file?

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
```

Regarding the base64 part of your question, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk) will show you where to get a base64 encoding library/protocol.

Comment: Thanks frank,
I only include #import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h> . Now it works great. Now only one problem is pending

NSString *hash = [HMAC base64Encoding];

This statement give warning
warning: 'NSData' may not respond to '-base64Encoding'

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

About the base64Encoding problem:
This is because NSData does not contains this method by default, you need to extend NSData with that. In this link is explained http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html  good luck!