# IPhone and HMAC-SHA1 with web services

Tags: iphone, web-services, xcode4, hmacsha1

This is my first question on stackoverflow so pls be gentle. I'm communicating with a web services in my iphone app and need to verify my request to the host. What i need to do is to take the url ex. "GET http://api.host.com/" together with a secret key running it via a class and generating a HMAC-SHA1 hash to veryfiy my identity. I have tried some example here on stackoverflow but i haven't found any example that worked for me. I got sample code of the .NET class that does what i need it to do  and now i need something similar that would work in Xcode for a iphone app. Here is the NET sample code:

```
public static void CalculateUrlDigest(string url, string secretKey) 
    { 
        byte[] utf8Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey); 
        byte[] utf8Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url); 
        HMACSHA1 crypto = new HMACSHA1(); 
        crypto.Key = utf8Key; 
        byte[] hash = crypto.ComputeHash(utf8Message); 

        Console.WriteLine("Base64: " + Convert.ToBase64String(hash)); 
    }
```

So if anyone could help me with a similar class/function for Xcode that would be great.

Best Regards

Hakan

Comment: I'm facing the same problem,
checkout this thread, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756492/objective-c-sample-code-for-hmac-sha1