# How to use the CCHmac() function in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

```
CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm algorithm, const void *key, size_t keyLength,
       const void *data, size_t dataLength, void *macOut);
```

- What will be the key?
- what will be the data?
- what will be the macOut?
- For example, I have API:

  ```
  https://
  somedomain/
  beta/
  men?
  key=[API KEY]&signature=[Signature]}
  ```

  How can I pass API key to CCHmac function and get the signature and make the complete API, e.g.:

  ```
  https://
  Somedomain/
  beta/
  men?
  key="Abcdefghi12345"&signature=jhfjkshkjfhsdkfhkshdkjfioeoiejafjnanjasbjfs="}
  ```

Can someone provide me good tutorial or sample code for `CCHmac` function? I looked on the web but I don't find anything.

Comment: Not sure if this is considered a duplicate, but a good start is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/756492/620197

Comment: I already saw this link. I want to understand how this things works ?

Answer (score 1):

`CCHmacAlgorithm algorithm` - set HMAC algorithm, for example, `kCCHmacAlgSHA256`;

`const void *key` - it's your API key (I recommend use a key-stretching function called PBKDF2 previously);

`size_t keyLength` - const, for example, `kCCKeySizeAES128`;

`const void *data` - some additional data, for example NSString;

`size_t dataLength` length of data;

`void *macOut` - returned hash. You can save it:

`uint8_t hmac[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
//Call CCHmac
NSData *hmacData = [NSData dataWithBytes: hmac length: CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];`

Check code from [this](http://www.sicpers.info/2012/07/password-checking-with-commoncrypto/) tutorial.